# How to use filter in BatchGetItem

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

I am fetching multiple items from dynamodb using BatchGetItem. But I need to filter items based on some conditions .

For example: I have a task table having id and status. I need to fetch items of id 1, 2, 3 where status=done.

```
#set($ids = [1,2,3])
{    
    "operation" : "BatchGetItem",
    "tables" : {
        "userTable": {
            "keys": $util.toJson($ids)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Filter expressions are not supported in `BatchGetItem`. Think of `BatchGetItem` as a batched version of the `GetItem` operation. `GetItem` only supports retrieving an item based on its primary key.

In your example, if the `status` column is not part of the primary key, then `BatchGetItem` or `GetItem` will not work for you.

Provided the task table in your example has **id** as partition key and **status** as regular column, there are multiple ways you can achieve the same result depending on the size of your table and the number of items you are expecting to be returned back.

#### Use `BatchGetItem` with filtering items in code

If the number of input items is relatively small, you could just use `BatchGetItem`, and then filter out in code (here in VTL) the ones where `status!=done`.

**Pros**: You don't need to change your table schema or add indices

**Cons**: You will pay for all the Read Capacity Units necessary to retrieve the items before filtering. There will also be a latency cost since your API will download potentially unnecessary items.

#### Use `Scan` With IN expression

If the table is small you can scan the entire table and provide an IN filter expression.

**Pros**: You don't need to change your table schema or add indices

**Cons**: You will have to scan the entire table, this will be slow and costly for large tables.

These recommendations are valid if you do not wish to change your table key schema.