# How to filter graphql results where sort key is in an array of strings

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, graphql, aws-appsync, dynamodb-queries, aws-appsync-ios

Application: AWS AppSync
Database: DynamoDB
Auth: Cognito

Partition Key: Id
Sort Key: Id

Goal: Return a collection of records where the sort key matches one of the values in an array of strings.

The partition key and sort key are used to organize parent/child relationships between content.  Root records have a generic Partition Key, which allows me to easily locate root records.  Example:

PK: root
SK: id0001

PK: root
SK: id0002

PK: id0001
SK: id0003

There are obviously other properties, but this demonstrates how I can quickly query for root records (anything with PK of root) or any children of a specific parent record (PK = parent id).

I want to pass the following array:
["id0001", "id0002"]
...and have it query for all root records where the SK contains one of the array values.

1) I tried using contains in the query expressions, which generates an error.  Apparently contains can only be used in filters.
2) I tried moving the contains logic to a filter, which generates an error.  Apparently I can't filter on sort keys within a filter.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This looks like a similar question to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56021621/how-to-use-filter-in-batchgetitem. In short, without changing fundamentally your schema, you either have to use a Scan to use an IN expression or you have to do the filtering in code.

Comment: Thank you.  I understand scans are process intensive, and slow.  Is it better practice to scan for 5 matching ids or make 5 efficient calls for the individual items?

Comment: It depends on the number of items in your dynamoDB table vs the number of elements you have in the filtering array. Usually the number of elements in the filtering array is smaller, so doing a batchGetItem might be the best approach.